# cy.task gives an error but no explanation, how can I fix it?

Tags: cypress

I'm using Cypress for frontend testing and I defined a task in cypress.config file.

```js
setupNodeEvents(on) {
            on('task', {
                downloads: downloadspath => {
                    return fs.readdirSync(downloadspath);
                },
                deleteFiles: directory => {
                    const files = fs.readdirSync(directory);
                    if (files.length === 0) {
                        return 0;
                    }
                    for (const file of files) {
                        fs.unlinkSync(path.join(directory, file));
                    }
                    return 0;
                },
            });
        },
```

And when I use it in my tests, it gives an error like this:

[image]

There's no explanation so, I don't know how to fix this error.

cy.task does a simple work, it just deletes all files in the cypress/downloads folder.

Comment: `cy.task()` runs node code so you can use `console.log()` in your code and debug with the terminal window.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, if the task throws an error it shows up in the Cypress log. You may get more info if you open devtools and click on the Cypress log entry.

Specifically, `fs.unlinkSync(path.join(directory, file))` is probably failing because there is a sub-directory in the directory, see [Node.js fs.unlinkSync() Method](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/node-js-fs-unlinksync-method/)

> The **fs.unlinkSync() method** is used to synchronously remove a file or symbolic link from the filesystem. This function does not work on directories, therefore it is recommended to use fs.rmdir() to remove a directory.

Since you are deleting `cypress/downloads` in the test, be aware Cypress does that for you

[Cypress Configuration - Downloads](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/configuration#Downloads)

> **trashAssetsBeforeRuns**  (default: true)
> Whether Cypress will trash assets within the downloadsFolder, screenshotsFolder, and videosFolder before tests run with cypress run.